# Modify LinearLayout content when dialog is clicked

Tags: android, view, checkbox, interface

I have created a `LinearLayout` which contains a set of checkboxes. Each checkbox, if clicked, generates a dialog, as follows:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("title");
        alertDialog.setMessage("dialog");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

            }
        });
        // Similarly for the NegativeButton
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Now, I want to delete the checkbox in case someone presses the positive button in the alert dialog. Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any view you can use

```
ll.removeView(view)// to remove particular view
ll.removeViewAt(position);// to remove view from particular position
```

use `android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"` in your xml and in your code:

`public void onCheckboxClicked(View v)` => You get a reference to the checkbox

Comment: Sure, but what is missing here is the reference to the view. I am inside the onClick method of the AlertDialog object. How can I access to the (external) reference to the view (i.e., the checkbox)?

Comment: MyActivity.this.theNameOfLinearLayout and MyActivity.this.theNameOfCheckBox

Comment: Moreover, suppose the checkbox is in a list of checkboxes. Is it possible to pass to the dialog its position?

Comment: use android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" in your xml and in your code: public void onCheckboxClicked(View v) => You get a reference to the checkbox ;-)